# Calculate: $\iint_{D}(x^2-y^2)dxdy$ D is the area inside the lemniscate $(x^2+y^2)^2=4(x^2-y^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> **Calculate:**
>
> $\iint_{D}(x^2-y^2)dxdy$
>
> D is the area inside the lemniscate $(x^2+y^2)^2=4(x^2-y^2)$

**My attempt:**

Define:

$x=r\cos\theta
,y=r\sin\theta$

Therfore,

$r^4\le4r^2(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)$

$r^2\le2(\cos 2\theta)$

Hence,

$0\le r\le 2\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}, 0 \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{4}$

(D is symmetric so we can limit $\theta$ to the first and second quarters and at the end multiply by two)

$$I=\iint_{\Delta }r^3cos2\theta d\theta dr=\int_{0}^{2\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}}(\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}r^3\cos 2\theta d\theta)dr=$$

$$\int_{0}^{2\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}}\frac{r^3}{2}\sin 2\theta|^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{0}dr=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}}r^3dr=2\cos^2 2\theta$$

I can't find my mistake because obviously the result can't be dependent on $\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have computed$$\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\int_0^{2\sqrt{\cos2\theta}}r^3\cos(2\theta)\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta.$$Can you take it from here?